# Reversing an array in C++ 14, my second array requires an extra element

Tags: c++, c++14

Hackerrank problem to reverse an array of size `n`.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-arrays/

Sample Input:

```
4
1 4 3 2
```

Sample output:

```
2 3 4 1
```

**Much of this code was already given, you can skip to the "This is what I did" section.**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split_string(string);



int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    string arr_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, arr_temp_temp);

    vector<string> arr_temp = split_string(arr_temp_temp);

    vector<int> arr(n);
    vector<int> arr2(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int arr_item = stoi(arr_temp[i]);
         
        arr[i] = arr_item;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        arr2[n-i] = arr[i];       
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";       
    }
    return 0;
}

vector<string> split_string(string input_string) {
    string::iterator new_end = unique(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), [] (const char &x, const char &y) {
        return x == y and x == ' ';
    });

    input_string.erase(new_end, input_string.end());

    while (input_string[input_string.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        input_string.pop_back();
    }

    vector<string> splits;
    char delimiter = ' ';

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t pos = input_string.find(delimiter);

    while (pos != string::npos) {
        splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, pos - i));

        i = pos + 1;
        pos = input_string.find(delimiter, i);
    }

    splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, min(pos, input_string.length()) - i + 1));

    return splits;
}
```

#### This is what I did

I declared another array named `array2` of size `n` to hold the reversed value which would then be printed.
I then wrote this snippet to reverse the array and copy it to `array2`:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        arr2[n-i] = arr[i];       
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";       
    }
```

This code works, but I feel like I have made a mistake since I have iterated `n+1` times in the `for` loop. I tried iterating `n` times but one element of the array got the value `0`. Indexing is also done differently since I am indexing from `1` to `n`. This is confusing to me, because I declared `array2` as size `n`. How and when did the vector get resized?

Is there a more elegant solution using `n` iterations? If not, why not?

Comment: It is indeed wrong because arr2[n] is not well defined. In your original solution, did you have arr2[n - 1 - i] and not arr2[n - i]? Remember, we start counting from 0, so the index of the last element in the array is n - 1, not n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first couple of lines show that this is shoddy code:

> ```
> #include <bits/stdc++.h>
>
> using namespace std;
> ```

`<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard header, and dragging all of `std` into the default namespace is a maintainability disaster (see other Code Review answers, ad nauseum).

None of the code which reads from `std::cin` ever checks whether the reading was successful, and there's no error handling whatsoever.

`arr` is a terrible name for a *vector*.  `arr2` is worse.

There's no need for handcrafted loops, when we could use `std::copy_n()` to read elements, and `std::reverse()` to reorder them.

Actually, there's no need to reorder the stored data - just write the output using a reverse iterator.

---

The low quality shows up when we analyse the memory accesses:

```
valgrind ./255602 <<<$'4\n1 4 3 2 5'
==5474== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5474== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5474== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5474== Command: ./255602-orig
==5474== 
==5474== Invalid write of size 4
==5474==    at 0x10B466: main (255602.cpp:30)
==5474==  Address 0x4d49000 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==5474==    at 0x480BDEF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5474==    by 0x10E741: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:115)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: allocate (allocator.h:173)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:460)
==5474==    by 0x10DE3F: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:346)
==5474==    by 0x10D60C: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:361)
==5474==    by 0x10CEA0: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:305)
==5474==    by 0x10C46C: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:511)
==5474==    by 0x10B3B6: main (255602.cpp:21)
==5474== 
==5474== Invalid read of size 4
==5474==    at 0x10B449: main (255602.cpp:30)
==5474==  Address 0x4d48fb0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==5474==    at 0x480BDEF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5474==    by 0x10E741: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:115)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: allocate (allocator.h:173)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:460)
==5474==    by 0x10DE3F: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:346)
==5474==    by 0x10D60C: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:361)
==5474==    by 0x10CEA0: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:305)
==5474==    by 0x10C46C: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:511)
==5474==    by 0x10B382: main (255602.cpp:20)
==5474== 
==5474== Invalid read of size 4
==5474==    at 0x10B495: main (255602.cpp:33)
==5474==  Address 0x4d49000 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==5474==    at 0x480BDEF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5474==    by 0x10E741: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:115)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: allocate (allocator.h:173)
==5474==    by 0x10E437: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:460)
==5474==    by 0x10DE3F: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:346)
==5474==    by 0x10D60C: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:361)
==5474==    by 0x10CEA0: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:305)
==5474==    by 0x10C46C: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&) (stl_vector.h:511)
==5474==    by 0x10B3B6: main (255602.cpp:21)
==5474== 
2 3 4 1 ==5474== 
==5474== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5474==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5474==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 78,336 bytes allocated
==5474== 
==5474== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5474== 
==5474== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5474== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Such failures fall short of *working*, in my opinion.

---

This is what a decent C++ program to do this looks like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // read the inputs
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read number of elements\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    elements.reserve(n);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin},
                n, std::back_inserter(elements));
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read element content\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // write the values, in reverse order
    std::copy(elements.crbegin(), elements.crend(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, " "});
}
```

See - no loops or arithmetic required.

Or, if you prefer an exception-based error handling strategy:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// read size from stream, then read that many elements into a vector
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> read_size_and_vector(std::istream& is)
{
    std::size_t n;
    is >> n;
    std::vector<T> elements;
    elements.reserve(n);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>{is}, n, std::back_inserter(elements));
    return elements;
}

int main()
{
    std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::badbit|std::istream::failbit);
    try {
        auto const elements = read_size_and_vector<std::string>(std::cin);
        std::copy(elements.rbegin(), elements.rend(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, " "});
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure&) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read the input\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying into another array, you could just print the original array in reverse way like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[n - i - 1] << " ";
std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
```

Also in your original code you're accessing vector out of bounds which may result in crash.

Answer (score 0):

Change the index like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        arr2[n-i-1] = arr[i];       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";       
    }
```